# Set axis limits of AxisArtist with plt.Circle in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I draw a circle:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axisartist.axislines import SubplotZero

fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(6, 6))

ax = SubplotZero(fig, 111)
fig.add_subplot(ax)

centreCircle = plt.Circle((0, 0), 1, color="black", fill=False, lw=2)

# Draw the circles to our plot
ax.add_patch(centreCircle)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

Everythin is OK:

[image]

But when I want to increase the limits of axes:

```
ax.set_ylim(-5, 5)
ax.set_xlim(-5, 5)
```

I failed.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may not understand the problem in completeness, because just adding `ax.set_ylim(-5, 5); ax.set_xlim(-5, 5)` to your code does in fact produce a nice plot.

But in general, you may use `ax.set_aspect("equal", adjustable="box")` to have the axes adjust to your limits when using equal aspect. So for asymmetric limits this could look like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axisartist.axislines import SubplotZero

fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(6, 6))

ax = SubplotZero(fig, 111)
fig.add_subplot(ax)

centreCircle = plt.Circle((0, 0), 1, color="black", fill=False, lw=2)

# Draw the circles to our plot
ax.add_patch(centreCircle)
ax.set_aspect("equal", adjustable="box")

ax.set_ylim(-5, 5)
ax.set_xlim(-5, 10)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: `ax.set_aspect("equal", adjustable="box")` solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

You can simply perform what you need without AxisArtist. If you can do without it, then here is the following example code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import Circle

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(7,7))
ax.add_artist(Circle((0,0),1,color='b'))
ax.set_xlim((-5,5))
ax.set_ylim((-5,5))

plt.show()
```

EDIT: redo with AxisArtist

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.axisartist as AA
%matplotlib "notebook"

fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(5,5))
ax = AA.Subplot(fig, 1, 1, 1)
fig.add_subplot(ax)
centreCircle = plt.Circle((0, 0), 1, color="black", fill=False, lw=2)
ax.add_patch(centreCircle)
ax.set_ylim(-5, 5)
ax.set_xlim(-5, 5)
plt.show()
plt.savefig('circle5x5v2.png')
```

[image]

Comment: Actually, I need it, because with AxisArtist I add the cartesian axes to the plot.

Comment: If I use `ax.set_ylim(a, b)` with different `a` and `b` matplotlib will reshape the circle what is bad. So I need to use `plt.axis('equal')` but it ignores `set_ylim`...

Comment: As soon as you start setting your x-axis or y-axis then it will be whatever shape, 'equal' only if you are careful. You can plt.axis('equal') before the ax.set_ylim(-5,5) n ax.set_xlim(-5,5) in my code above and it will work and produce the same figure, above.

Comment: Try plt.axis([-5.,5.,-5.,5.], 'equal') but it will create the same figure as what I have described in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

You just need

```
ax.set_ylim(-5, 5)
```

or even

```
plt.ylim(-5, 5)
```

Comment: @RomaKarageorgievich: Try using `fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))`, i.e., a square figure

Answer (score 0):

I think you just try to set 
 ylim(-5,5)